# Excluding a string in a preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have two preg_match statements that work find by themselves, but when I use both of them the second one breaks the first one;

```
$message = preg_replace("!(http(s)?://(www\.|m\.)?(youtu\.be/|youtube\.com/watch\?v=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+))!", 
"<p><a href= '/viewpost.php?messageid=$message_id'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$5/0.jpg' width='536' border='1'></a><p>", $message);

$message = preg_replace("!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i", "<a href='$1' target='_blank' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'><b>$1</b></a>", 
$message);
```

I've posted this recently and received a recommendation of setting up arrays for the patterns and conditions, then applying them together in a single preg_match statement, but this does not seem to address the issue (although the code looked nicer).

My idea is to set up a pattern in the second statement that will exclude a pattern found in the first statement (in this case, "youtube.com/" and "youtu.be/") but I can't get it to work;

```
$message = preg_replace("!(http(s)?://(www\.|m\.)?(youtu\.be/|youtube\.com/watch\?v=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+))!", 
"<p><a href= '/viewpost.php?messageid=$message_id'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$5/0.jpg' width='536' border='1'></a><p>", $message);

$message = preg_replace("!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)/^(?\!\youtube\.|youtu\.be/)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i", "<a href='$1' target='_blank' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'><b>$1</b></a>", 
$message);
```

I think I'm close to finding a way, but I'm not catching something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. In your second preg_replace you have a few errors.

1. Remove the `/^` after the http-part (that slash isn't there and `^` matches only the start of the string)
2. The regex doesn't compile because the right syntax to exclude is `?!` (meaning not followed by) and that doesn't work well with escaping. I've chosen `#` as open- and close-mark.
3. Because you've already replaced `youtu.be/...` to `img.youtube.com/...` you should exclude that url instead.

Working code:

```
$message = 'http://youtu.be/watch?v=123 http://www.google.com';
$message_id = 6;

$message = preg_replace("!(http(s)?://(www\.|m\.)?(youtu\.be/|youtube\.com/watch\?v=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+))!", 
"<p><a href= '/viewpost.php?messageid=$message_id'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$5/0.jpg' width='536' border='1'></a><p>", $message);

$message = preg_replace("#(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)(?!img.youtube.com/vi/)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~\#?&;//=]+)#i", "<a href='$1' target='_blank' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'><b>$1</b></a>", 
$message);

echo htmlspecialchars($message);
```

Besides that, a solution with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) might be easier to read and much easier to extend with future options (for example inline images if url ends with `.jpg`):

```
$message = 'http://youtu.be/watch?v=123 http://www.google.com';
$message_id=6;

$callback = function($matches) use ($message_id) {
    $youtube = preg_replace("!(http(s)?://(www\.|m\.)?(youtu\.be/|youtube\.com/watch\?v=)([-|~_0-9A-Za-z]+))!", 
"<p><a href= '/viewpost.php?messageid=$message_id'><img src='http://img.youtube.com/vi/$5/0.jpg' width='536' border='1'></a><p>", $matches[0], -1, $count);
    if ($count) {
        return $youtube;
    } else {
        return "<a href='".$matches[0]."' target='_blank' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'><b>".$matches[0]."</b></a>";
    }
};

$message = preg_replace_callback("!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Z?-??-?()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i", $callback, $message);

echo htmlspecialchars($message);
```

(note that the use of a Closure `$callback = function() { ... }` requires at least PHP 5.3, otherwise you can use a named function)

Comment: This totally solved the problem.  Thank you, Peter, I appreciate the guidance.